# Adding a between date constraint in Oracle SQL with parent/child tables

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have two tables Study and Case. The Study is the parent table and Case is the child table. I have to add a constraint such that the CASE_DATE in the Case table is within it's parent table Study's START_DATE and END_DATE.

```
Study
-------
ID
START_DATE
END_DATE

Case
-----
ID
STUDY_ID
CASE_DATE
```

Comment: What happens if someone updates the STUDY table setting the END_DATE to something *before* an existing child row in CASE table?

Comment: Not possible in my situation. Study table is created first and then never modified. All Child tables are created subsequently.

Comment: You cannot implement this with a constraint. You can do this with triggers. Search for  BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: *"Study table is . . . never modified."* Famous last words. If that's a real requirement, then revoke update and delete privileges on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is much simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_date
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON CASE
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE

  StartDate STUDY.START_DATE%TYPE;
  EndDate STUDY.END_DATE%TYPE;

BEGIN

SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE
INTO StartDate, EndDate 
FROM STUDY
WHERE ID = :NEW.STUDY_ID; -- Assuming ID is the primary key, i.e. unique

IF NEW.STUDY_ID NOT BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001, 'Study date not in valid range');
END IF;

END;
/
```

However, there are some pre-requisites:

- ID in table STUDY is a unique key
- START_DATE and END_DATE in table STUDY must not change after insert into table CASE, otherwise you have to write another trigger also for table STUDY
- You have a foreign key constraint from STUDY.ID to CASE.STUDY_ID

As long as these pre-requisites are present the trigger should work.

In case you **have** to do this with a constraint you can do it also. Create a function that checks the date, e.g.

```
create or replace function IsDateValid(StudyId in number, CaseDate in date) 
return boolean is
declare
   StartDate STUDY.START_DATE%TYPE;
   EndDate STUDY.END_DATE%TYPE;        
BEGIN        
    SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE
    INTO StartDate, EndDate 
    FROM STUDY
    WHERE ID = StudyId; 

    return CaseDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate;
END;
/
```

Then create the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE case ADD CONSTRAINT check_date CHECK (IsDateValid(STUDY_ID, CASE_DATE));
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the basic referential integrity is being enforced through a standard foreign key constraint, and that no columns are allowed to be NULL.

In order to properly create this validation using a trigger a procedure should be created to obtain user-specified locks so the validation can be correctly serialized in a multi-user environment.

```
PROCEDURE request_lock
  (p_lockname                     IN     VARCHAR2
  ,p_lockmode                     IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT dbms_lock.x_mode
  ,p_timeout                      IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 60
  ,p_release_on_commit            IN     BOOLEAN  DEFAULT TRUE
  ,p_expiration_secs              IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 600)
IS
  -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique issues implicit commit, so place in its own
  -- transaction so it does not affect the caller
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_lockhandle                   VARCHAR2(128);
  l_return                       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique
    (lockname                       => p_lockname
    ,lockhandle                     => p_lockhandle
    ,expiration_secs                => p_expiration_secs);
  l_return := dbms_lock.request
    (lockhandle                     => l_lockhandle
    ,lockmode                       => p_lockmode
    ,timeout                        => p_timeout
    ,release_on_commit              => p_release_on_commit);
  IF (l_return not in (0,4)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Return Value ' || l_return);
  END IF;
  -- Must COMMIT an autonomous transaction
  COMMIT;
END request_lock;
```

This procedure can then be used in two compound triggers (assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cases_exist
  FOR UPDATE ON study
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of updated studies (assuming numeric)
  g_ids sys.odcinumberlist;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
  -- Reset the internal study table
  g_ids := sys.odcinumberlist();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the updated studies
  IF (  :new.start_date <> :old.start_date
     OR :new.end_date <> :old.end_date)
  THEN           
    g_ids.EXTEND;
    g_ids(g_ids.LAST) := :new.id;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_studies
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT
           sty.column_value id
    FROM TABLE(g_ids) sty
    ORDER BY sty.column_value;
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_id study.id%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM study sty
         INNER JOIN case cse
           ON (   cse.study_id = sty.id
              AND cse.case_date NOT BETWEEN sty.start_date AND sty.end_date)
    WHERE sty.id = p_id;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any updated study there exists a case outside the start and
  -- end dates. Serialise the constraint for each study id so concurrent
  -- transactions do not affect each other
  FOR r_study IN csr_studies LOOP
    request_lock('STUDY_CASES_' || r_study.id);
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_study.id);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Study ' || r_study.id || ' has cases outside its dates');
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER study_dates
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON case
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of studies (assuming numeric)
  g_study_ids sys.odcinumberlist;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
  -- Reset the internal study table
  g_study_ids := sys.odcinumberlist();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the updated studies
  IF (  INSERTING
     OR :new.study_id <> :old.study_id
     OR :new.case_date <> :old.case_date)
  THEN           
    g_study_ids.EXTEND;
    g_study_ids(g_study_ids.LAST) := :new.study_id;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_studies
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT
           sty.column_value id
    FROM TABLE(g_study_ids) sty
    ORDER BY sty.column_value;
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_id study.id%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM study sty
         INNER JOIN case cse
           ON (   cse.study_id = sty.id
              AND cse.case_date NOT BETWEEN sty.start_date AND sty.end_date)
    WHERE sty.id = p_id;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any updated case it is now outside the start and end dates of
  -- the study. Serialise the constraint for each study id so concurrent
  -- transactions do not affect each other
  FOR r_study IN csr_studies LOOP
    request_lock('STUDY_CASES_' || r_study.id);
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_study.id);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Study ' || r_study.id || ' has cases outside its dates');
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
/
```

Comment: Wow I thought this would be fairly simple. I am trying to get an idea in SQL so I can put this in my LiquaBase

Comment: This solution is a huge overkill. You don't need to look anything, Oracle does it for you. There is also no need for a compound trigger.

Comment: @Wernfried Although, given the pre-requisites in your solution, this is 'overkill', in the situation where the study dates could be altered two triggers are required. Oracle does *not* do the required locking in this situation to prevent the constraint being violated in a multi-session environment where separate sessions are amending the dates for both tables for the same study at the same time. In order to *guarantee* the constraint is not violated the explicit locking is required. The compound trigger make the locking as fine-grained as possible to improve scalability and to reduce deadlocks